# PyGame only shows black screen

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

```
import pygame, sys
#from pygame.locals import *

def load_map(path):
    f = open(path + ".txt","r")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    data = data.split("\n")
    game_map = []
    for row in data:
        game_map.append(list(row))
    return(game_map)

#main
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("test1")
main_map = load_map("map/main_map")

#main Variables
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
window_size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size, 0, 32)
scroll = [0,0]
display = pygame.Surface((350,250))

#tiles
dirt1 = pygame.image.load("tiles/grass1.png")
water1 = pygame.image.load("tiles/grass.png")

#player variables
playerx = 350
playery = 350
player_image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("player/player.png").convert_alpha(), (150, 150))
player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = (80,50))

#button variables
move_right = False
move_left = False
move_up = False
move_down = False

game_map = load_map("map/main_map")

while True:
    screen.blit(player_image, [playerx, playery], player_rect)

    y = 0
    for layer in game_map:
        x = 0
        for tile in game_map:
            if tile == "G":
                display.blit(dirt1, (x*16, y*16))
            if tile == "W":
                display.blit(water1, (x*16, y*16))
            x += 1
        y += 1

    if move_right == True:
        playerx += 2
    if move_left == True:
        playerx -= 2
    if move_up == True:
        playery -= 2
    if move_down == True:
         playery += 2

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                move_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                move_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                move_up = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                move_down = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                move_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                move_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                move_up = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                move_down = False

    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(display, window_size),(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Hello i'm new to pygame and I was trying to make something with tutorials, but I didn't wanted to copy evrything from the tutorials I watch, and I tried to figure it my own. However, I can't figure this one out. I had a black screen when I run the program. Can anyone tell me what did I did wrong? I cannot figure where I did do wrong

Comment: You are blitting some images to `display`  and others to `screen`, then overwrite display with screen. Pick one surface to blit your images to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to target surfaces, `screen` and `display`. However, just 1 of this surfaces can be associated to the window.

> ```py
> screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size, 0, 32)
> ```

Therefore you will only see the parts of the scene that are drawn on the `screen` *Surface*, but not the parts that are drawn on the `display` *Surface*. Remove the variable `display` and replace `display` with `screen`

As a quick fix you can simply set `display` with `screen`:

<s>`display = pygame.Surface((350,250))`</s>

```py
display = screen
```